# INSERT 150TB data into the table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two table Tbl1 and Tbl2. Tbl1 size is 150 TB.

I have do insert like:

```
INSERT INTO Tbl2
SELECT *
FROM Tbl1
```

What's way to do this much more effectivly? I just created columnstore index on Tbl2, I have't any other ideas

Comment: You're blowing up the transaction logs, etc.  Do it in smaller chunks.  Write a loop to process a million rows (or similar) at a time.

Comment: @MatBailie Thank you. I'll try

Comment: @dfundako No, there are just 4 millions rows

Comment: *"there are just 4 millions row"* and the size of the table is 150TB?!

Comment: If 4million rows equals 150TB then you have 37.5MB per row!  What do you have in there???  *(I'd only process ~1,000 rows at a time.)*

Comment: @MatBailie No) I mean 4 miilion rows in example which you provide me) Rowcount in my table is 2754281492